# Why \n is needed to make text blink on console?

Tags: c

I was asked to write a program to blink the given word without using `clrscr` function in c and I have written following code

when I add `\n` in the printf then only it works fine i.e. it blinks the text on console

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int j=10;
    while (j--)
   {
       printf("BLINK\n");
       sleep(1);
       system ("clear"); 
       sleep(1);
   }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I remove `\n` the console is blank i.e. `blink` text doesn't appears on the console even once, why this is so?

```
printf("BLINK");
```

Comment: Note that your question (about the newline and `printf`) is totally unrelated to your title. In the future please use the title as a short summary of the question you're actually asking about. And please take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Many terminals support [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Try this: `puts("\33[5mBLINK\33[0m");`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry dude i will take care of it nexttime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Buffering***.

Output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is by default *line buffered*. That means the text written to `stdout` is put into a buffer only, and is not *flushed* (actually written to the device) unless either the buffer is full, or a newline is written.

Information about this should be in any good book, tutorial or class.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by adding a flush of stdout.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int j=10;
    while (j--)
   {
       printf("BLINK");
       fflush(stdout);
       sleep(1);
       system ("clear"); 
       sleep(1);
   }

    return 0;
}
```

But system("clear") will probably make code reviewers cry blood, so maybe consider something like backspace escape sequence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int j=10;
    while (j--)
   {
       printf("BLINK");
       fflush(stdout);
       sleep(1);
       printf("\b\b\b\b\b     \b\b\b\b\b");
       fflush(stdout);
       sleep(1);
   }

    return 0;
}
```